# Expected number of hash collisions

Tags: python, hash, collision

I feel like I'm way overthinking this problem, but here goes anyway...

I have a hash table with M slots in its internal array.  I need to insert N elements into the hash table.  Assuming that I have a hash function that randomly inserts am element into a slot with equal probability for each slot, what's the expected value of the total number of hash collisions?

(Sorry that this is more of a math question than a programming question).

Edit:
Here's some code I have to simulate it using Python.  I'm getting numerical answers, but having trouble generalizing it to a formula and explaining it.

```
import random
import pdb

N = 5
M = 8

NUM_ITER = 100000

def get_collisions(table):
    col = 0
    for item in table:
        if item > 1:
            col += (item-1)
    return col

def run():
    table = [0 for x in range(M)]

    for i in range(N):
        table[int(random.random() * M)] += 1

    #print table
    return get_collisions(table)

# Main

total = 0
for i in range(NUM_ITER):
    total += run()

print float(total)/NUM_ITER
```

Comment: how do you want "triplet" collisions measured ?

Comment: Whatever makes the most sense I guess.  So I'll go with counting it as two collisions (one per new element added after the first)

Comment: The best measure appears to be the amount of work to retrieve all items, which is `SUM(x * (x+1) /2)` with X is the number of items in a bucket, and the sum is over all buckets.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll find the answer here: [Quora.com](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/How-can-I-calculate-the-expected-number-of-cache-hits). The expected number of collisions for **m** buckets and **n** inserts is

`n - m * (1 - ((m-1)/m)^n)`.

Comment: There is also a proof of this on [the Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/birthday-problem-expected-number-of-collisions).

Comment: Answer should include the proof.

Comment: Is there a table available for generic m values (such as 2^32) ?

Comment: IMHO, number of collision is not same as number of elements sharing same bucket/slot. In the context of B'day paradox, if 4 persons share same B'day, then answer to the latter question (# of person sharing same B'day) would be 4. However, for the former question, the # of B'day collision is often considered to be 4-1=3. The rationale behind this is that, without any three of the four persons, there is no collision. The difference is minor and yet worth noting so as to not get confused.

Comment: Is there a way to show the variance of the number of collisions?

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the `SUM(x*(x+1)/2)` metric can be found [here](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions/), and the *expected value* appears to be `(n/2m)* (n+2m -1)`.

Don't know about the variance, IANAM.