# Numbers of collision in a hash table

Tags: c, hash

I'm doing a hash table for store elements in this range: 2000000-20000000 of values.

examples:
17664658-8,7587458-8,7338375-4,5741259-2.....

In a sample of 100000 elements the number of collisions is about 23939 and in a sample of 1000000 elements the number of collisions is about 439870. I don't know much about hash tables, but this numbers of collisions are not a little high?

I read that in a controlled range of numbers you can have a good hash function fairly uniform , but do not know how or where to start , any advice ?

this is my hash fuction.

```
int hash(char* clave,int m) { //m is the size of the table (about the double of the elements to be stored)
        int number=0,i=0;
        /// 
        while(isdigit(clave[i])){ //i don't use the last 2 characters. 
            number+=(clave[i++]-'0');
            if(isdigit(clave[i]))
                number*=10;
        }
        /// mutiplication method
        float dis,R;
        R=0.6106154;
        dis = R*(number) - floor(R*(number));
        int result = (int)(dis*m);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what's the size of your hash table? are you using powers of two, by any chance?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant for the 100000 elements the size of the table is 178144.

Comment: Btw, just for fun, try a table size of 178141 or 178151 instead (closest primes, in case you're wondering).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the number of collisions is not too high, in fact it's about what you'd expect. The formula for the [expected number of collisions in a hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104504/expected-number-of-hash-collisions) with a uniform, random hash function and m buckets and n insertions is:

```
n - m * (1 - ((m-1)/m)^n)
```

For your case:

```
m = 178144
n = 100000
```

Plugging the numbers in gives:

```
100000 - 178144 * (1 - ((178144-1)/178144) ^ 100000)
= 23476.674
```

and the observed number of collisions is 23939. So there is nothing wrong with your hash function.

Comment: i tried a bigger m and the numbers of collisions passed from 23k to 6k. so what i do? a bigger m, a different hash function? or the important thing is the collision-resolution?

Comment: Increasing m will lead to less collisions, because if there are more slots available to insert items into then the less likely two items will end up assigned to the same slot. there is no reason to change the hash function, because it is already performing nearly optimally. so just increase m