# Fastest HASH algorithm for millions of UINT64 RGBZ graphics pixels

Tags: c, performance, hash, rgb

Of the 3 leading hashing algorithms I have tried on many millions of 48 bit RGB pixels, the performance difference was minimal. xxHash by Yann Collet had the least collisions and the lowest product of time (bad) * collisions (bad):

```
Time=0.454 sec  XXH32_HASH_RGB        0.2486% Hash Collisions  =>     
1       time*coll=1.6258  << Lowest Time * collisions
Time=0.490 sec  fasthash32_HASH_RGB   0.2554% Hash Collisions  => 
1.0273  time*coll=1.7878 
Time=0.460 sec  MurmurHash3_x86_32    0.2542% Hash Collisions  => 
1.0225  time*coll=1.6421
```

xxHash - Fast Hash algorithm
Copyright (C) 2012-2015, Yann Collet

MurmurHash3 was written by Austin Appleby, and is placed in the public ...

fasthash32 // Compression function for Merkle-Damgard construction.

Is there a PixelMunchingMonster hash I am overlooking?

Each algorithm is fed 6 bytes of data at a time from an in-memory array and outputs a 32bit value.

```
for(pidx=0; pidx < num_pix; pidx++)  {  // II is uint16 *, need 3/pixel
  time_event(E_XXH32_HASH_RGB, tsa, E_TIME_EVENT, debug);  // HASH! HASH!
  //MurmurHash3_x86_32((const void *)(fmem+pidx*3),6,seed,(void *)(&h32));
  //h32=(unsigned int)fasthash32((const void *)(fmem+pidx*3), 6, seed);
  h32=(unsigned int)XXH32((const void *)(fmem+pidx*3), (size_t) 6,seed);
}
```

GCC compiled for win7/64, fine tuned for my metal, Intel 2700k:

gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -O4 -ffast-math -finline-functions -m64 -Ofast -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7 -Ic:/bin/xxHash-master -Lc:/bin/xxHash-master c:/bin/stddev.c -o c:/bin/stddev.g6.exe

=================================================

@BrianP007 Do you mean 99.76%? If so either something's wrong with your calculation or you got very very lucky. Even with an ideal uniform hash function, 217MB / 48bpp ~= 36M pixels should result in only 99.58% non-collisions. –  MooseBoys 1 hour ago

---

0.2486% Hash Collisions:  89877 Diff_Color_Same_Hash / 36152320 pix

I hash out all 36M pixels, crunch the 48 bits of RGB into 32 bits of hash and then increment the hash data value every time that hash is calculated.

There are 3 case for total of 36152320 pixels (7360*4912)

A) Unique pixel, 1 hit  => 27558538

B) Same color on 2+ pixels  => 8503905

C) Same hash, different RGB == COLLISION!  => 89877

Quantumly random data from a badass sensor is the only cromulent explanation!

uint16_t *fmem  is the RAW file BLOB in memory. PIDX is the PIXEL_InDeX, 0-36M
Num_Pix=36152320

The code is pretty idiot proof. Whew!

```
for(pidx=0; pidx < num_pix; pidx++)  {  
  h32=(unsigned int)XXH32((const void *)(fmem+pidx*3), (size_t) 6,seed);
}
```

I used the LOST magic number, 4815162342, for the seed.  Am I on The List now?

=======================================================

Collision counting code fix and new collision/performance rates...

I found a bug in the collision handling code. I was only looking at pairs of the sorted hashes. This works fine for unique hashes mapping to exactly one pixel/rgb and for cases with 2 occurrences of the same hash due to either a collision or exactly 2 points sharing that hashed color.

For cases of 3 instances of a given hash, the third one would have slipped by as a unique on the next loop.

The fix was to drill down to the last occurrence of a hash value and send the RGB set mapping to the Pixel_IDs mapping to the hashes to a uniquing function.

If it returns 1 unique RGB for every pixel having that hash value, then there is no collision: Result:  unique_colors++, collisions  unchanged

For return of N > 1 RGB =>  unique_colors += N, collisions += N

So, if 4 pixels had common hash values  and  2 distinct colors (3 of 1, 1 of the other, or 2 and 2, makes no difference),  the result is 2 collisions and 2 distinct colors.

```
fasthash32                     => 0.6474% Hash Collisions; 0.439, 0.440, 0.440 sec
XXH32                          => 0.6296% Hash Collisions; 0.439, 0.439, 0.438 sec  
MurmurHash3_x86_32 => 0.6448% Hash Collisions; 0.466, 0.435, 0.434 sec
```

The Murmur hash might have had a very slight speed lead, but XXH32 had fewer collisions so I went with XXH (to make as few sense as possible)

For extra credit, Which is the more efficacious InLining directive?

XXH and Murmur had an incompatibility with respect to ""FORCE_INLINE"

---

```
I:\br3\pf.249465> gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -O4 -ffast-math         -finline-function
s -flto -m64 -Ofast -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7 -Ic:/bin/xxHash-master -Lc:/
bin/xxHash-master c:/bin/stddev.c -o c:/bin/stddev.g6.exe
In file included from c:/bin/bpb.h:8:0,
                 from c:/bin/stddev.c:44:
c:/bin/xxHash-master/murmur3.c:16:0: warning: "FORCE_INLINE" redefined
 #define FORCE_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline
 ^
In file included from c:/bin/bpb.h:5:0,
                 from c:/bin/stddev.c:44:
c:/bin/xxHash-master/xxhash.c:90:0: note: this is the location of the     previous d
efinition
 #    define FORCE_INLINE static
```

NOTE: Each .c/.h line commented out of project include file while testing the other so each would build their own way.

Comment: Your metric (time * collisions) makes no sense.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by hashing 48 bits into 32 bits?  Are the pixels truly random or is there some clustering?

Comment: >> Your metric (time * collisions) makes no sense
Time is BAD. I want it done NOW!
And, collisions are bad. But, it might be interesting to draw only the pixels with colliding hash values to see what that picture looks like with 1/4 of 1% of the pixels. It could be informative.
But, the least (bad * bad) must be the best?  How would you rank 3 so similar Hash results? With a car, you mix price, insurance, mileage, theft rate, sexiness, ... Insurance rate and mileage are not apples to apples either.

Comment: >>  Are the pixels truly random or is there some clustering?
With a bunch of sky, you might get a big clump of Blue. Forests  -> greens. But in general, the colors from the new, ultra-sensitive sensors with 14/15/16 bits per channel give very wide coverage of the color spectrum.
Counting colors before/after a process will measure damage. Measuring the different between the same raw file processed in various color spaces will quantify whether a space is cramping your data.  Run sensors head to head!
I need general purpose, FAST tools for 217 MB .RAW files (nanoscopic attention span  <;o)

Comment: (time_to_get_into_the_car_and_start_the_engine * chance_to_be_involved_in_an_accident) is (bad*bad) as well. Also makes little sense.

Comment: What's the point of hashing pixel-by-pixel?  If you just want to test which pixels are (probably) the same between two images, then the cost of hashing 48 bits must far outweigh the advantage gained from comparing 32-bit quantities instead of 48-bit quantities.  Even if you do the comparison channel-by-channel.

Comment: >>wildplasser:  (time_to_get_into_the_car_and_start_the_engine * chance_to_be_involved_in_an_accident) is (bad*bad) as well. Also makes little sense.  <<  You keep stating that it makes "no sense". I have 3 hashes, each with ~ the same perf and each with about the same collision rate. Would you keep all three because it made such "good sense".  Your repeated insistence that making a choice based on  slim differences "makes little sense" is itself non-nonsensical.   How do you ever make it out of the Cereal Aisle?  :)

Comment: John Bollinger::  What's the point of hashing pixel-by-pixel?

Intrinsic image quality can be measured by counting the distinct colors in a picture, especially on small areas. 

Experiment:Process a sharp, highly colorful camera RAW file through adobe Camera Raw with minimal, neutral settings and vary only the color space, export to photoshop and save as 16b bit .RAW files named after the color space. 

crop a small, highly detailed area out with ImageMagick on the same coordinates. Then count the colors. ....

Comment: Preliminary results:
`
    pf-2015.0531-249465.nef, crop 577x428+5084+2270 -> 246956 pixels
    ProPhoto     RGBs=239794 = 97.1% ->  2.9% dup, 1 dup clr/34 pix  
    ColorMatch  RGBs=211643 = 85.7% -> 14.3% dup, 1 dup clr/ 7 pix  
    adope 1998  RGBs=234273 = 94.9% ->  5.1% dup, 1 dup clr/19 pix
    speciousRGB  RGBs=225558 = 91.3% ->  8.7% dup, 1 dup clr/12 pix
`
SORRY FOR THE BAD FORMAT :(

Comment: I guess calculating the standard deviation of H channel in HSV space makes much more sense than hashing the whole thing. With the presence of noise, everything is distinct, unless some kind of classification is applied.

Comment: @BrianP007: The question is nearly unreadable now that you've editted in snippets of rambling conversations from comments.  I didn't look at the edit history, but as it is now, it's mostly noise.  I have no idea if there's a point in there somewhere, or if MooseBoys's suggestion of using the low bits works for whatever you're using this hash for.  It looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

If your RGB values represent actual image data spanning a significant portion of the representable range of each channel, the lower bits should be reasonably well-distributed and uncorrelated. As a result, a simple concatenation of the lower bits should yield few collisions and be extremely fast to calculate:

```
hash(RGB) = (R & 0x7FF) << 21 | (G & 0x7FF) << 10 | (B & 0x3FF);
```

Comment: I tried sorting 10 bits red, 12 green and 10 blue and got a bunch of duplicates. Rather than just dropping them, I wanted a hash to somehow include them. I have 99.76 non-collisions with xxHash in  .47 seconds on a 217 MB .RAW file

Comment: @BrianP007 Do you mean 99.76%?  If so either something's wrong with your calculation or you got very very lucky.  Even with an ideal uniform hash function, 217MB / 48bpp ~= 36M pixels should result in only [99.58%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104504/expected-number-of-hash-collisions) non-collisions.

Comment: MooseBoys, added more detail in edit above, would not fit here. The numbers come out right at < 1/4 of 1% collisions, < 90k on 36M??

Comment: @BrianP007 Are you sure you're not counting the number of hashes with more than one key?  For example if 5 pixels map to the same hash do you count that as 1, 4, or 5 collisions?

Comment: MooseBoys, you were right about the funky collision counting... TYVM!  Notes and performance/collision rates added to original question above