# Expected number of uniquely hashed items

Tags: data-structures, hash, probability

Given a closed hash table with `M` slots, if I hash `N` items into that table uniformly at random what is the expected number of items that hash uniquely to a slot (i.e., what is the expected number of slots with exactly 1 item)?

Note that this is similar to but subtly different from the [expected number of collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9104504/149138). For example, a 2 element table that hashes 4 elements with slot counts `[2, 2]` or `[3, 1]` both have 2 collisions, but the former arrangement has zero uniquely hashed items and the latter has one.

Comment: "the former arrangement has one uniquely hashed item and the latter zero"- ???

Comment: The answer is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem. If you want some help understanding that, you probably should ask on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @shihab ooos I reversed that, thanks!

Comment: I believe it depends a lot on how you compute hash, and data set. Result changes with a perfect ditribution instead of a gaussian one.

Comment: @owairc - right, I forgot to specify "unformly at random", i.e., essentially assume the hash function as uniformly random as possible (not a "perfect" has though - that has a different meaning). Fixed now. I don't think it depends on anything else: it's really just a math problem formulated as a data structures question: I could have equally asked "After selecting N values from a uniformly random discrete distribution with M values, how many values will have been selected exactly once?"

Comment: @JimMischel - thanks for the link and while it's certainly related, those formulas are all oriented around finding the probability of a single collision, not the number of non-colliding elements (and you can't go from one to the other in a simple way, e.g., via subtraction).

Comment: The section below that, "Other birthday problems" answers the question directly. In particular, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people. *In an alternative formulation of the birthday problem, one asks the average number of people required to find a pair with the same birthday.*

Comment: Sorry @JimMischel - I'm just not seeing it. In the "hash" terms I formulated the question in, that answering the specific question _What is the average number of items that need to be inserted before the first collision occurs_. That's only slightly different than the original birthday problem (which is _number of items before there is a 50% chance of at least one collision_), and doens't help me here. If I were to formulate my question as a birthday problem it would be: _With N people in a room and if a year has M days, how many people will **not** share their birthday?_

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. I see now that your problem is a bit more difficult because collisions aren't necessarily uniformly distributed. I suspect you'll have a much better chance of a useful answer if you ask the question on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @JimMischel - I was hoping to avoid it (I have to learn the notation all over again), but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2501855/346316) it is.